# Extract strings from HTML table populated by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to easily fetch strings from specific cells using my javascript function (see below) however now the database is being populated by javascript instead of test information in html I can no longer do this. Is there a different way to refer to individual cells of tables populated with javascript as opposed to html?

**JS to populate table:**

```
var unmatched =0;
    $(document).ready(function(element){
        $('#records').hide();
        $('#unmatched').hide();
        $('#fileForm').hide();
        $('#totalUnmatched').append('<a style="color:#ffffff;">'+unmatched+'</a>');
        $('#matching').hide();
    });
```

**JS to get string from individual cells (works on html only version):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#scoutRecordTable tr').click(function(){
        var rowIndex = $(this).index();
        var Row = document.getElementById("scoutRecordTable");
        var string = document.getElementById("scoutRecordTable").rows[rowIndex].cells[0].innerHTML;
        string += ' ';
        string += document.getElementById("scoutRecordTable").rows[rowIndex].cells[1].innerHTML;
        $("span").html(string);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you talking about a table in the browser or data sitting in a database that is in a server far far away from your browser? JS deals with the browser and what is in it.

Comment: It's data on a separate server.

Comment: Do you know the server language PHP, Python, etc., the DB SQL, Mongo,etc. If you do, put them in tags and then change your question to fit those tags. JavaScript may be only part of the solution. JS deals in front end matters, anything in a browser, HTML, CSS,etc. You can use JS to request data from server, but ultimately data from a database is controlled by the server. If you were planning on writing a table w/o HTML...what were you planning to make the table with?